# Pass server side control's client ID in javascript function as parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I pass server side asp control's client ID in javascript function.
I tried like this.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbMyocardial" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onClick="return f1('<%rdbMyocardial.ClientID %>')">
      <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

But when I try to print the value in javascript, like this,

```
function f1(list) {
    alert(list);
    return true;
}
```

It shows <%rdbMyocardial.ClientID %>. How can I get the client side ID of server control?
Also how can I set it from both HTML and from server side code?

Comment: take a look  at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362338/how-do-i-pass-a-server-controls-actual-client-id-to-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like this  : document.getElementbyId('<%=rdbMyocardial.ClientID%>')

Comment: you can use like this : f1(this); because this pass whole object from where you called it

Comment: this wont work for me because I need to pass two server controls from single place

Comment: function f1() {
   var ddlSupCSR = document.getElementById('<%=rdbMyocardial.ClientID%>');
alert(ddlSupCSR.options[ddlSupCSR.selectedIndex].innerHTML.toString());
    return true;
}


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbMyocardial" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onClick="return f1()">
      <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= rdbMyocardial.ClientID %>`.