# How can I use a JavaScript variable to get an ASP.NET ClientID inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, controls

I'd like to be able to get a ASP.NET control's ClientID inside of a JavaScript function. I also would like to be able to pass in a var containing a control name so that different controls can use the same function.

For example, if I wanted to use a control named Button1, this works fine:

```
function doStuffToButton1Control()
{
    var buttonControl = document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>');
    //do stuff with buttonControl
}
```

But I get an error when I try to make the control name dynamic. I'm trying to string together the ClientID call, like so:

```
function doStuffToGenericControl(controlName)
{
    var dynamicControl = document.getElementById('<%= ' + controlName + '.ClientID %>');
    //do stuff with dynamicContorl
}
```

I've tried using double quotes or single quotes when creating the string, but the error is always "Too many characters in string literal" or "Too many characters in character literal". The control exists and the name passes correctly (as tested by an `alert(name)`).

Is there a better way to go about this, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

**Update:** This function will be on a master page. Any number of child pages will be calling it. For example, one child page might have an ASP control that calls it like so:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="doStuffToGenericControl('Button2')">...</asp:LinkButton>
```

But another page might have this ASP control that also calls it:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Button4" runat="server" OnClientClick="doStuffToGenericControl('Button4')">...</asp:LinkButton>
```

However, these controls' IDs often change by ASP.NET on render, so they end up looking, for example, like `MainContent_Button2` instead of just `Button2`. To get around this, I traditionally just used `<%= Button1.ClientID %>`, but since I want any number of controls to be able to use this one function, I'm having a bit of trouble.

**Update 2:** I was able to use `this` along with a `getAttribute` call to get what I needed. (Obviously this will only work when the control you are referring to is the one you are clicking, but that is what I needed) Like so:

```
function doStuffToGenericControl(controlName)
{
     var controlID = controlName.getAttribute('id');
     var control = document.getElementById(controlID);
     //do stuff with control
}
```

Comment: please provide more code how this method is called? what argument are you trying to pass to this method?

Comment: Once a page is loaded any server sided C# code is done. Any server sided `<%%>` stuff is parsed out as plain text to the javascript function (assuming it actually spits something out). Is there a reason you don't know the controls actual ID from the client side of things?

Comment: I updated my post @rownage, please take a look

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362338/how-do-i-pass-a-server-controls-actual-client-id-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: Thanks @latr0dectus, a combination of that and Arsen's answer helped me to get what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'`<%= Button1.ClientID %>'` is something that replaced in with control id on asp.net page render,

but when you pass variable in client side, you should pass id and use it without any % scops

so try this

```
function getGenericControl(control)
{
    var dynamicControl = control;
    alert(dynamicControl);
    //do stuff with dynamicContorl
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use <%= ClientID %> to generate parameters for the method above, so just change OnClientClicks like this and use method above

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="doStuffToGenericControl(this)">...</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: It is not clear, how this function is called, so some more code of this will make the answer more clear

Comment: @ScottSelby is right...This is my problem. I'll update my question.

Comment: After trying your update, the JavaScript function is showing the name as `<%=Button2.ClientID%>`, instead of the full control name which I expect to be something like `MainContent_Button2`. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can just pass reference of control, instead of id, use this, see edited post please

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...When i use `this` it passes `javascript:__doPostBack('Button2','')` and then when i use `document.getElementById(control)` it returns `null`.

Comment: actually you are doing something wrong, it should work, please drop LinkButton code again

Comment: I was able to use getAttribute('id') on `this` and then use `getElementById()` on that result to get what I needed (see updated answer). Marking yours as correct because it got me to where I needed to be. Thanks!

Comment: great, I am glad I could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing control name why don't you pass the control itself by passing this in the function like this:

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="doStuffToGenericControl(this)">...</asp:LinkButton>
```

and your function will be :

```
function getGenericControl(control)
{
    var dynamicControl = control;
    alert(dynamicControl.id);
    //do stuff whatever you want with dynamicContorl
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I ended up doing based on ArsenMkrt's updated answer. I just used `getAttribute` instead of `dynamicControl.id`

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using a class if that is possible,

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')
                > -1) {
            elems[i].innerHTML = content;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Snuffleupagus - damn youre right , trying to answer fast - edited answer