# how to get the client id values in javascript and asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

In my asp page, i have three text and 2 label box.On text box `onblur` event i called a javascript function by passing textbox clientid.But i cant get the textbox or label box value from the id i passed.

this is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function num_validate(cid,cid1) {

        var patt = /^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
        if (cid1 == "t1") {
            var value=this.document.getElementById(cid).value; //failed
            this.document.getElementById(cid).focus(); //failed
            var ff = document.getElementById('<%= l1.ClientID %>').value);//failed
        }
 }

</script>


 <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" onblur="javascript:num_validate(this,'t1')">   </asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="l1" runat="server" Text="3"></asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="t2" runat="server"  onblur="javascript:num_validate(this,'t2')"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="l2" runat="server" Text="5"></asp:Label>

  <asp:TextBox ID="t3" runat="server"  onblur="javascript:num_validate(this,'t3')"></asp:TextBox>
```

I could not able the text box,label box value by using either cid,cid1...

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Comment: So basically you are using the control's id's in order to get there value by passing there id's through the function. Correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is wrong

```
var value=this.document.getElementById(cid).value; //failed
this.document.getElementById(cid).focus(); //failed
```

use instead

```
var value=cid.value;
cid.focus();
```

Comment: i100 you are right when you are use "this" why pass second argument there ?

Comment: ok i called, without second argument also...that is not a problem

Comment: @i100, Couldn't able to get the label box value using var l1 = document.getElementById('<%=l1.ClientID%>').value; what is the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what I tried and worked:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        function num_validate(element)
        {
            var Cid = element.getAttribute('id');
            var value;
            if(Cid = 't1')
            {
                value = element.value;
                alert(value);
            }

            else if(Cid = 't3')
            {
                value = element.value;
                alert(value);
            }
        }

</script>


   </head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

  <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" onblur="num_validate(this, t1);">
  </asp:TextBox>&nbsp;

  <asp:TextBox ID="t3" runat="server"  onblur="num_validate(this,t3);"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If it didn't work you could have a look at a similar situation @[How do I pass a server control's actual client Id to a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362338/how-do-i-pass-a-server-controls-actual-client-id-to-a-javascript-function). Hope that helps.